# htaccess 404 redirect not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I am trying to setup a custom 404 page for my website using: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` but when I add this, going to domain.com/dslkjflsdkjflskdjf doesn't redirect to the 404 page. Instead, it redirects to my homepage where mostly everything on the page is broken.

I'm wondering if this mod_rewrite.c module is the cause of this, I've tried modifying it (taking L out, adding the redirect inside the module, etc) but no luck.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but I think your server won't recognize a 404 error because every request is redirected to your index.php. You have to determine in the index.php if there is a 404 error and send the header with the header() function.

Comment: Is there a way I can rewrite that module so I can just use ErrorDocument to catch the 404?

Comment: I don't know what your index.php does but I think it  controls the output and loads it dynamically from a database so only your index.php will know if there is no content available.  So your index. php has to catch the error and show the error page. So in your index.php if the user requests content that dies not exist send a 404 error with header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found'); and after that include your 404.php

Comment: I've tried your solution but the module directive is executed before PHP has time to send a 404 error to the header.

Comment: Yes, every request that is not to an existing file is redirected to your index.php with the original request as a parameter in the query string. So if you want to display the content the user requested, the index.php should handle this. And if the index.php looks up the database or whatever source you use and it notices that their is no content metching the request, it has to send a 404 header to the client. Maybe you can explain what your index.php does exactly or post it (if it's not too long) so I can help you further.